# Where do Warpers go when they teleport?

Tags: subnautica

When a Warper teleports away, where does it go? To another location in the game? To an inaccessible location? Or does it leave the game entirely until it's time for it to warp back in?

Answer (score 9):

It depends on why it teleports to. If the Warper is dealt enough damage to "kill" it, it will warp away (and despawn) instead of leaving a corpse.

Conversely, if the Warper is merely patrolling (has not noticed the player, or they are being actively ignored), it warps back to a spawn point (whereupon it will resume patrolling again).

Comment: When you say "it will warp away instead of dying", where does it warp away to?

Comment: @TenMinJoe I mean, instead of having a dying animation (as other fauna will), it simply teleports away and is gone. I'll edit that to be more clear.

Comment: But they *don't* go back to their spawn point. I watched a Warper through several cycles, far enough away that it didn't notice me. When it warped away, as far as I could tell, it was just... gone. It was only after a few minutes that it finally came back to its spawn point, in a second warp.

Comment: @HiddenWindshield At times I think they teleport outside of the map, behind geometry. This seems to happen to most NPCs, and I think it has to do with the LOD of geometry not lining up properly in the distance, allowing them to easier get stuck the further away they are from the player.